# expr command not found? Why is expr not found but everything else is?

Tags: bash

I have spent several hours trying to make the following piece of code work

```
    PATH="C:\Ben\MyPictures"
    echo $PATH
    MY=`expr 2 + 2`
```

but this will not work because "expr: command not found". The only thing I've dug on StackOverflow are pathing issue (I.E. set my environment variable), but if that's the problem, why would other functions like echo, let, and declare already work fine?

For more context, this is on a near-fresh installation of window's cygwin. My question is why can't I find expr?

Comment: what does `which expr` show?

Comment: With bash (and POSIX) shells, you also have the `MY=$((2 + 2))` syntax available as well.

Comment: It currently doesn't show anything. All I want is for the code to run without crashing.

Comment: Adding `:/bin:/usr/bin` to your current `PATH` should restore the functionality (presuming your `expr` is located in the normal `/usr/bin/`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have modified your `PATH` to have only 1 directory(therefore it cant find `expr`). You must append your new path to `PATH` and not replace existing `PATH` values, like this:

```
export PATH="$PATH:C:\Ben\MyPictures"
```

Also instead of calling an external process `expr` for calculation you can use the bash's builtin arithmetic evaluation:

```
$ echo $((2+2))
4
```

Edit:

Yes those would work because they are **not** executable files found from directories listed in `$PATH`.

Instead they(`echo`, `type` etc) are functionality provided by the `bash` shell itself called shell built-ins.

Type out `type echo` and `type expr` to know what type of command is it(alias/shell builtin/executable file etc.)

Shell built-ins help can be usually found out by `help shellBuiltin` where as we use `man` pages for executable files.

PS: `type` itself is a shell built-in(see `type type`)

Comment: This is very plausible. I will try it in the morning and if so award best answer.

Comment: Sure enough this worked. The one thing I don't understand still is why 'expr?' Why not 'echo'. Even let and declare still work while changing the path variable.

Answer (score 3):

The path variable `PATH` is used to find the location of standard binaries that ship with your environment.  In fact system environment variables are usually capitalized( for example `HOME` ).

In your command :

```
PATH="C:\Ben\MyPictures"
```

You have accidentally(or intentionally?) replaced the standard paths to the standard binaries by `C:\Ben\MyPictures` so that command interpreter, bash here, can no longer find `expr`.  When you use capitalized variables,say PATH, you could do:

```
if [ -z "$PATH" ] #check if a variable is empty
then
PATH="C:\Ben\MyPictures"
else
PATH="$PATH:C:\Ben\MyPictures"
fi
```

The better option indeed is to use small letters for user defined variables :

```
path="C:\Ben\MyPictures"
#in this case you should not get an error for expr but
# I am not sure how a Linux-Like environment handle character case.
# check that out.
```