# Cant install Python3 on Linux

Tags: python, linux, aws-cli

For AWS CLI i need to install Python on my Linux Server.

After i do the following:

```
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.4/Python-3.6.4.tgz
tar xf Python-3.6.4.tgz
cd Python-3.6.4
./configure
```

I get a lot of the same errors

`./configure.lineo: line 472: expr: command not found`

Some can help me to find a solution?

I also tried diffrent Version of Python2 and Python 3, but none worked and gave me the same error.

Comment: is `expr`  command working in your terminal ?

Comment: @ShalithaSuranga `expr: command not fund`

Comment: `/usr/bin/expr` working ?

Comment: in my `bin` Folder is no `expr`

Answer (score 0):

expr is mostly always present in /usr/bin... There could be a problem with the `PATH` environment variable. This post may be helpful: [expr command not found? Why is expr not found but everything else is?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37269832/expr-command-not-found-why-is-expr-not-found-but-everything-else-is)

Comment: i went threw it before i asked my question, but since im not setting any PATH i have a hard time to find the answer which is helping me in my case

Comment: what happens if you type `whereis expr`?

Comment: Something is wrong with the OS user config. It seems that the PATH variable is not set or wrongly set. Is yours a new install? did you created the user manually? 
type `echo $PATH` to inspect it. You should at least see something like:`/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin` 
I would take a look to the `.bashrc` file on the user's home directory, it could be that the file permissions are wrong, the file does not exist...

Comment: Is it important to know that i only access the Server via ssh?

Comment: i finally could test ist i got on the `echo $PATH` the answer `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin`